# Execute SET command in c program

Tags: c, shell, command, set, execute

I created a little mini shell and it let's the user enter a command like 'ls' and it will list the contents of the directory like it's supposed to using execv() in my code, but that doesn't seem to work for when the user enters something like 'set name="bob"'. I've been looking all over the place for what I should use in my code to execute a set command when the user enters it and the best I can find is system(), but that still isn't working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like one of my school first-year's projects. A WHOLE LOT...

Answer (score 1):

`set` is a shell-builtin command, not an external command (indeed it needs to be to have the intended effect, which is to modify a shell variable within the shell process itself).

This means that you need to look for and handle `set` within your shell itself, by adding the named variable to some internal data structure that tracks shell variables (or updating it if it already exists there).

Comment: So does this mean I'll have to write my own set command in my minishell that will do something similar to the built-in set command?

Comment: @user1186710: Right - if you want to support `set`, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a fork-and-exec or a system(), the command is really being run in a separate process. What happens in that process (like setting an environment variable) does not affect the parent's environment. (A separate issue is that `set` doesn't actually create an environment variable. You'd need `export` in [ba]sh or `setenv` in [t]csh to do that.)

So you need to code your mini-shell to handle the `set` command explicitly, rather than passing it off to another program.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at setenv(3) and getenv(3). These are functions for changing and reading environment variables from within a C program.

Comment: But that won't let me create variables will it?

Comment: From the man page: "The  setenv()  function adds the variable _name to the environment with the value _value," So, yes it does.